# How does this work? It gives the answer but I don`t understand it.

Tags: c#

How does the following code work? It gives the answer how I want. But I want to know how it works?

```
public static void ShutDownComputer()
    {
        ManagementBaseObject outParameter = null;
        ManagementClass sysOs = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");
        sysOs.Get();
        sysOs.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
        ManagementBaseObject inParameter = sysOs.GetMethodParameters("Win32Shutdown");
        inParameter["Flags"] = "8";
        inParameter["Reserved"] = "0";
        foreach (ManagementObject maObj in sysOs.GetInstances())
        {
            outParameter = maObj.InvokeMethod("Win32Shutdown", inParameter, null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is using [Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx) to invoke the [Win32Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394058(VS.85).aspx) method.

```
// Creates a class which represents the model of the OS:
ManagementClass sysOs = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");

// Binds the class to the management object
sysOs.Get();

// Enables user priveledges for the connection, this is required to perform actions like shutdown
sysOs.Scope.Options.EnablePriviledges = true;

// Set the flag to indicate a "Power Off" (see the method link above for others)
inParameter["Flags"] = "8";

// According to MSDN the "Reserved" parameter is ignored hence its just being set to 0
inParameter["Reserved"] = "0";

// iteratve over all instances of the management object (which would be one in your case)
// and invoke the "Win32Shutdown" command using the parameters specified above.
foreach (ManagementObject maObj in sysOs.GetInstances())             
{             
    outParameter = maObj.InvokeMethod("Win32Shutdown", inParameter, null);             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using .net managed objects to interact with the [WMI subsystem of windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), specifically the [`Win32Shutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394058%28VS.85%29.aspx) method of the `Win32_OperatingSystem` Class.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier for you to understand what's going on if you use the Win32 API '[InitiateSystemShutdownEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376874(v=VS.85).aspx)'. This is a C/C++ API, so you need to 'import' it into C# like this: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/InitiateSystemShutdownEx.html